# If $\sum a_{n}$ conditionally convergent. ST $\sum n(\log n)(\log\log n)^{2} a_{n}$ is divergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

My attempt: Let $b_{n}=\sum n(\log n)(\log\log n)^{2}$ and it is divergent by comparison test. 
We know that $\sum a_{n}$ is conditionally convergent, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n} =0$.

Claim: if $\sum b_{n}$ is divergent then there exist a $a_{n} \rightarrow 0$ and $\sum a_{n} b_{n}$ is divergent.

Is there is any mistake if I use this result to show divergence?

Comment: In your claim, do you want $b_n>0$?

Comment: For your problem in the title, not the claim, we have $a_n=(-1)^n / n(\log n)(\log\log n)$.

Comment: I gave you an answer, why do you need any hint?